# convert string array to object array

Tags: java, arrays

I was asked to use an array to create a phonebook which would read in a text file.
However I am having trouble each line on the text file into my object array.

so my solution was to create an array of type String then make my object array = to string array... but thats the problem.

Is there any way of my directly using the **Scanner class** to read in my text and save it into an object array as Scanner class's next() method is type string... and my array is type object... ?

thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your code, please?

Comment: All strings are objects, but that's not the kind of objects that they wan you to use. You can freely add strings to `Object[]` arrays, though.

Comment: I don't understand the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    lines.add(sc.nextLine());
}
String[] array = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
```

Comment: I can't use ArrayList :C

Comment: why can't you use arraylist?

Answer (score -1):

ArrayList is the key All you need to do is convert your Strings to arrayLists and then you can add or pop the elements more easily